# Defining (X)HTML node code content in phpStorm

Tags: html, phpstorm

For our HTML templates, we use a content aggregation engine based on a namespaced XML-based markup syntax that has some custom tags defining various fragments of the template. For example, for js code we have:

```
<foo:js src="http://..." />
<p>
   This is regular HTML; this document with the namespaced tags will be 
   aggregated into HTML by our metalanguage aggregator.
</p>
<foo:js>
    console.log('bar');
</foo:js>
```

I'd be very happy if these could be parsed and edited as JS code or JS reference tags (the self-closing one) in phpStorm. I figured out the "Language injections" settings is designed for that, but I can't find any documentation how to achieve this. The "Places Patterns" seems to be the key to this enigma. So can anyone provide some hints into how to do this using Language Injection(s)?

Also, for the rest of the tags, as a simple form of completion/validation, is it possible to specify a default XML schema (i.e. XSD) for the namespace? I mean, apart from explicit `xmlns:foo` tags, because our markup files represent fragments so we'd have to add quite a number of these on quite a lot of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following injection will highlight javascript in all `<namespace:js>` tags:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, I need some help with this: I am at the "Language injections" Settings dialog; I click the "Add" button and I have a drop menu with 9 options. The one that takes me to a dialog similar to your printscreen is "9. XML Tag injection"; I configure it precisely as you described, but nothing happens. I don't know if it's relevant: the file type is tagged "php" (because we also allow php code inside). In the "2. Generic PHP" insertion dialog I only have the ominous "Places Patterns" thing...

Comment: Is there, some feature or plugin that inspects the edited document and where you can find the current node and path? I mean from the editor GUI's persepective. I know Eclipse had such a feature where you could find out every editor node context path, highlight class, etc.

Comment: Ok, correction: it does seems to work after restarting phpStorm...

Comment: So just half question remaining: how to define a default ns bind to remove `Namespace 'foo' is not bound` errors?